# Google Cloud Builds Trigger for GitHub Repo says "No tag matches" Always

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

## Build Trigger Setup

- Setup a Build Trigger to a GitHub Repo

  - Trigger Type: Tag
  - Tag(regex): .*
  - Cloud Build Configuration file
  - Substitution variables:
  - _DEPLOYMENT_ENV: staging 
    The config is below: 
    [image: Trigger Config]

## Things I've Looked at

- I've checked out the GitHub Applications and Authorizations. Google Cloud Platform is approved
- The [Google Cloud GitHub Marketplace Plugin](https://github.com/marketplace/google-cloud-build) is on for the repo and functions. I get a greencheck mark on pull requests after it builds the containers

## Current Results and Expectation

I expect there to be tags matched because the repo has some tags. I push some new tags and nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you setup your integration as a from Google Cloud GitHub Marketplace or are you doing it from Google Cloud Platform > Cloud Build > Triggers?

Answer (score 1):

> Note: Google Cloud Build's GitHub Marketplace Plugin is still in Alpha, so its features are not reliable and it is not unusual to run into breaking changes... and there is no active support for it.

The screen you are seeing is from Google Cloud Platform -> Cloud Build -> Triggers. It is different and unrelated to the Google Cloud plugin found inside the GitHub Marketplace (I know, it is confusing).

The triggers you setup currently pull in GitHub repos into Google Cloud Source Repositories before your triggers are executed.

The GitHub plugin, I have been having some issues with it these few days and I think they are introducing some new breaking changes on it soon, but when it worked, it does not require any triggers and purely looks at the cloudbuild.yaml file to do builds automatically. I had to create separate scripts inside the cloudbuild.yaml to setup different build based on tags / branches (Cloud Build Triggers let you do all these inside the UI), but what you get as part of the GitHub plugin is this "GitHub Checks Events" (the green check / red cross) next to the corresponding commits in GitHub and also a very brief details page. The GitHub plugin is currently acting weird on me and I am in the process of switching over to use Cloud Build Triggers until they have sorted it out.

[image]
[image]

I think they are working on something to bridge the difference between Google Cloud Build Triggers and the Cloud Build GitHub plugin... just a feeling from the current log messages I see inside Cloud Build...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am actually using the Google Cloud Build's GitHub Marketplace Plugin to build my projects container on every commit.
However, with our current deployment process works we only push certain commits to staging, prod etc.. I was hoping to have a tag trigger prod / staging.... So I still need to figure out what's going on with the tags. I filed a bug report too. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124106037

Comment: @VinayAnantharaman The GitHub plug-in does not currently support any of these natively. Let me share my cloudbuild code for doing this manually in a bit. It’s not really a big since the tags problem you saw is another unrelated part of Google Cloud Build that uses another way to trigger builds.

Comment: @VinayAnantharaman checkout https://gist.github.com/williamli/f09c9a2c34b89fbf9fcf10f733b3f879 . I basically have a cloudbuild.yaml file that the GitHub plugin will trigger. Inside that file, I have commands to look at the branch (in your case will be tags), and from there, it triggers the actual cloudbuild logic in a separate cloudbuild-something.yaml file. Two builds will happen in parallel and finish together.